# Handle ConstraintList with persistent solver

Tags: pyomo

I want to try using persistent solver for an algorithm that iteratively adds new constraints to the problem, and want to avoid having to completely rebuild the file given to the solver before each iterations.

Before using persistent solver as described on https://pyomo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/solvers/persistent_solvers.html, I used a `ConstraintList` object to iteratively add my new constraints without having to name them individually. I thought this was a very elegant solution and I want to see if there is a way to notify the persistent solver when a new constraint is added to the `ConstraintList`.

In the docs, it is writtent that

```
m.c2 = pe.Constraint(expr=m.y >= m.x)  
opt.add_constraint(m.c2)
```

where `m.c2`is a constraint to be added to the model with persistent solver. What would be the equivalent line to notify the persistent solver that a change was done to the `ConstraintList`, once that a constraint was added in it?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you create your constraint list

```
m.Cut_Defn = pyomo.ConstraintList(noruleinit=True)
```

And then you can add constraints in your constraint list:

```
m.Cut_Defn.add(some_number >= your_variable + some_other_number)
```

If you solve before the `.add()` then you'll find another solution than solving after the `.add()`. So you can think like: it implements the new constraints on the fly, and you have to resolve your model, if you want that constraints to be in your optimization.

Comment: Can you confirm/prove/show me the docs that the method `.add(` from a constraint list will update the model that was previously uploaded only once in the persistent solver instance? It is very important since solving with those constraints gives the same result as solving without these (and I can confirm that they will change the results). And I didn't forget to solve after changing the constraint list.

Comment: I can't really prove you if it will update, but you can try something like: Assume your objective to minimize is x, and you have a constraint, which says x>=10, and if you add x<=11 in your constraint list, and if you resolve that model, u should get in-feasibility error from your solver. So that you can understand it adds the constraint.

Comment: you might find an interesting answer to my question on the Pyomo forum here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pyomo-forum/TI0bWesN62o Thanks for the time and help!